# How to get SQL Server's DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to get SQL Server's DateTime in this format `2020-04-29 08:31:50.813`

This is my Code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void getDTOServer()
    {
        string sqlStr = string.Format(@"use [{0}] 
            SELECT GETDATE() AS 'DTOServer'
        ", DatabaseName);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr);

        string DT = Man.getSqlDataset(cmd).Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.Flush();
        Context.Response.Write(DT);
    }
```

The problem is when I'm running this query `(SELECT GETDATE() AS 'DTOServer')` in SQL Server I get correct output but C# gives me output like this `29-Apr-20 8:31:51 AM`.

What I want is `2020-04-29 08:31:50.813`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: I don't know what `Man` is, but you can and should just use `ExecuteScalar` (which returns `object`, and cast to `DateTime`. Then, if you need a string, use the ToString overload that takes in a format, like shown in Nithin's answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled `Man` is my dll (SQL Manager) which handles all connection open, close, etc

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the `ToString` method of a proper `DateTime` object

```
ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got a solution. Convert `DateTime` to `VARCHAR`

Like This:

```
        [WebMethod]
        public void getDTOServer()
        {
            string sqlStr = string.Format(@"use [{0}] 
                SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 126), 'T', ' ') AS 'DTOServer'
            ", DatabaseName);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr);

            string DT = Man.getSqlDataset(cmd).Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

            Context.Response.Clear();
            Context.Response.Flush();
            Context.Response.Write(DT);
        }
```

The issue was C# was converting it to local format because the data type was DateTime

Comment: Better to do your formatting in C# than SQL Server.

Comment: No, that's not the issue. The issue is that you're messing around with strings when you're using `DateTime`. You see, [`DateTime` has no concept of format](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/), not in SQL Server and not in c# - and local / universal has to do with time zones, not string representation formats. Instead of messing around with strings, populate c#'s `DateTime` struct from SQL Server's `DateTime`. Also, you don't need the `use` statement - `GETDATE()` works on the server level, it doesn't matter what database you're connected to.